# Which C++ version is supported for all iOS apps supported by Apple?

Tags: c++, ios

I want to use `std::variant` in iOS app but iOS-11 does not support `std::variant`. I get compilation error:

```cpp
a.cpp:55:17: error: 'visit<(lambda at a.cpp:43:19) &, std::variant<foo, bar, baz> &>' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 11.0
    return std::visit(...);
```

I still want to support iOS 11. I could have avoided writing code this way if there was a way to know which C++ version is supported for all the iOS apps. Are there ways to know which C++ version is supported for all iOS apps supported by Apple at any point in time?

Comment: If all mean ALL ios versions, maybe you can just check which apple-clang compiler was present at that time and what features of C++03 / 11 was already implemented in it.
Otherwise, what about setting the target ( e.g. `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYEMENT_TARGET` ) and see what you can use?

Comment: We use absl::variant as a workaround.